# javacv: application terminates with opencv_contrib.createLBPHFaceRecognizer

Tags: android, opencv, javacv

I am experiencing with Face Recognition and followed all the steps for the `OpenCV` static initialization [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-static-initialization).

But when I execute this:

```
com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.createLBPHFaceRecognizer(2,8,8,8,200)
```

My application terminates without generating any LogCat response. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this kind of behaviour while back(not with the same function). At that time, the issue was that I used some parameters, that were not allowed, therefore it crashed without giving any log information. If android side crashes without logcat output,  then most likely the issue lies withing the C++ code.

If you are going with the static initialization, then it is wise to review the libs folder if all of the required .so files are there. It usually gives logcat output if something is missing, but it is good to be sure.